# ext js4 to sencha touch convertor

Tags: extjs4, sencha-touch, code-conversion

Is there any code converter available for converting code for extjs4 to sencha-touch?

I am trying to put my efforts by reviewing docs. But I am getting stuck at many points.
Please let me know if anybody is having any idea.

Comment: @nandkumar tekale - thank you for editing my poorly formatted question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no code converter because there is no 1 on 1 conversion possible. At best you can reuse models, stores an possibly controllers (if they are written loose-coupled from the views). Views will always be different.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?122534-ExtJS-4-Sencha-Touch

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no such tool available for such code migration. Please refer following links for more details -

[Sencha Touch and ExtJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358977/sencha-touch-and-extjs)

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?150710-Migrating-ExtJS-app-to-Sencha-touch-2.0